# Issue With Local Location Based Notifications Not Triggering

Tags: ios, swift, location, region

I am trying to get my app to fire local location-based notifications when entering a region, but they aren't firing for some reason, either in the foreground or background. I don't believe the problem is with registering for authorization of notifications or with region monitoring (if I'm wrong, please let me know), but I'm not certain where the problem is.

Here is my code in AppDelegate:

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    locationManager.delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { (Granted, Error) in
        if (Error != nil) {
            self.showAlert()
        }
    })

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    return true
}

func showAlert() {
    let badAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You will not be able to receive notifications from us since you denied us permission to present them to you.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    badAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(badAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func handleEntryEvent(forRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
        let entryAlert = UIAlertController(title: "WARNING!!!", message: "You are now entering an area notorious for crime! Please use extereme caution, and if possible, leave the area immediately.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        entryAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(entryAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let identifier = region.identifier
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "WARNING!!!"
        content.subtitle = "You are now entering an area notorious for crime! Please use extereme caution, and if possible, leave the area immediately."
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = 1

        let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func handleExitEvent(forRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
        let exitAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Leaving a Crime Zone", message: "You are no longer in an area that has a lot of crime. Please avoid that area you just left in the future if possible!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        exitAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(exitAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let identifier = region.identifier
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Leaving a Crime Zone"
        content.subtitle = "You are no longer in an area that has a lot of crime. Please avoid that area you just left in the future if possible!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = 1

        let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}
}

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLCircularRegion {
        handleEntryEvent(forRegion: region)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLCircularRegion {
        handleExitEvent(forRegion: region)
    }
}
}
```

And code in Map View Controller

```
func region(withCrimeZones crimeZones: CrimeZone) -> CLCircularRegion {
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: crimeZones.coordinate, radius: crimeZones.radius, identifier: crimeZones.identifier)
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true
    return region
}

func addRadiusOverlay(withCrimeZones crimeZones: CrimeZone) {
    mapView?.add(MKCircle(center: crimeZones.coordinate, radius: crimeZones.radius))
}

func startMonitoring(crimeZones: CrimeZone) {
    let region = self.region(withCrimeZones: crimeZones)
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
}

func stopMonitoring(crimeZones: CrimeZone) {
    for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
        guard let circularRegion = region as? CLCircularRegion, circularRegion.identifier == crimeZones.identifier else { continue }
        locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: circularRegion)
    }
}

func locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates(_ manager: CLLocationManager, crimeZones: CrimeZone) {
    let region = self.region(withCrimeZones: crimeZones)
    locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
}

func locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates(_ manager: CLLocationManager, crimeZones: CrimeZone) {
    let region = self.region(withCrimeZones: crimeZones)
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
    print("Monitoring failed for region with identifier: \(region!.identifier) because of \(error)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Location Manager failed with the following error: \(error)")
}

extension Map: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT: I have updated the code above with more code and what I have changed so far!**

Comment: You have embedded the location manager delegate methods inside the `if granted`.  That isn't right

Comment: Where should I move them to?

Comment: They should be functions in the class like the other functions.

Comment: Ok, let me test things out with my app and then I will let you know if they work out or if there are still issues with it.

Comment: Hi Paul, I updated my code and did some test, but the notifications aren't still firing. I have updated my original post to include what I have now and more code to analyze.

Comment: @RolfCosmoAnthony Have you been able to figure out the problem? I have the same problem and can not fix it...

Comment: No. I have discontinued developing this app for something else, so I don't have an answer as to a fix for this.